# Angular Submit POST form

Tags: angular, form-submit

I need to send some data to an external page and then go to those page, is a page of a payment gateway.

Without Angular i would create a form with the destination page in "action" and "method" post, submitting this form i would get what i need.

The form would be so:

```
<form action="https://merchant.sparkling18.com/ppt-paygate/checkout" method="POST" name="submit1app8" id="submit1app8" >

    <input id="sqck.errorReturnUrl" name="sqck.errorReturnUrl" value="http://www.tantosvago.it/errore.asp" />

    <input id="sqck.userReturnUrl" name="sqck.userReturnUrl"  value="http://ws.tantosvago.it/1APP8/getstate1app8.php"/>

    <input id="scqk.customInfo" name="scqk.customInfo"  value="{&quot;answer&quot;:&quot;42&quot;,&quot;now&quot;:&quot;Wed Jul 02 21:08:31 UTC 2014&quot;}" />

    <input id="sqck.submitOrderData" name="sqck.submitOrderData"  value="eyJvcmRlciI6eyJtZXJjaGFudEl"/>

    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" />

</form>
```

Now, with angular i need to to the same thing without a form.
I must post some datas (now i set all fixed datas) to an external page and go there to complete the payment, and this is what i do (in "app.js"):

```
tantoSvagoApp.controller("checkoutController", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window, $httpParamSerializerJQLike ) {

        $scope.submit1app8 = function() {


            var parameters = {
                                "sqck.errorReturnUrl": "http://www.tantosvago.it/errore.asp",
                                "sqck.userReturnUrl": "http://tstest.tantosvago.it/1APP8/getstate1app8.php",
                                "scqk.customInfo": "{answer}", 
                                "sqck.submitOrderData": "eyJvcmRlci"
                            };


            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'https://merchant.sparkling18.com/ppt-paygate/checkout',
                data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(parameters),
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
            }).then(function success(response) {
                 console.log(response.data);
            }, function (response) {
                 console.log("Errore " + response.data,response.status);
            });

        };

});
```

This is my HTML, a simple button that call my function:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/assets/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="tantoSvagoApp">

    <div ng-controller="checkoutController">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="conferma_ordine()">Conferma Ordine</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

But nothing happen, i can't go to the destination page (https://merchant.sparkling18.com/ppt-paygate/checkout)

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:angular]? Also our question is vague. Please read through [ask] a good question and provide an [mcve]. If you are getting an error you need to supply the error details.

Comment: i'm sorry, i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a HTTP POST request in Angular, you would first have to import the HttpClient Module. The Angular Docs provide useful information on this.

https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request